# All that glitters is confusing!

Tags: semantics, grammar

1. "All that is gold does not glitter"
2. "Not all that is gold glitters"

The first phrase appears in Lord of the Rings, modified from Shakespeare, and contextually implies that "Aragorn is vastly more important than he looks"[1], suggesting a meaning more in line with the second phrase. But taken together literally, the two phrases above are contradictory. What gives?

1.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_that_is_gold_does_not_glitter

Comment: I suspect, aside from proverbs enjoying greater word order freedom than typical prose, the location "not all", and especially "not all that ...", have only become commonplace more recently, and earlier on, the now-confusing and admittedly ambiguous form "all ... is not ..." was more prevalent.
I'd make this an answer if I had solid evidence, but all I have is [this Google N-grams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+all,not+all+that&year_start=1800). It has flaws: there's no comparison with the competing form, and it doesn't account for the colloquial "it's not all that!".

Comment: This is known as a [Quantifier-Negative Ambiguity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/q-neg.html). Both quantifiers and negatives have ***Scope***, and both have unusual syntactic affordances, like Quantifier-Float (which relates _All the boys didn't leave_ and _The boys didn't all leave_) and Neg-Fronting (which relates _All of them have never left_ with _Never have all of them left_). Whenever there is more than one negative, or more than one quantifier, or a quantifier and a negative, in a clause, there will be ambiguity. And it's worse when you mix in modals, which are operators, too.

Comment: @jlawler I would consider making that an answer. Your citation is of your own material, which may not be ideal, but then in turn it contains pointers to third-party citations, so...

Comment: You might like to ask this at [literature.se].

Comment: Though the two shouldn't be taken together, as only the first is in Tolkien?

Comment: @LjL: The material is an online answer to an newsgroup question on the same subject, back in the Ordovician, before the web. Q-Neg ambiguities have been known for 50 years or so; they're hardly news.

Comment: @jlawler Happy New Year (and to all readers too!). If you have a spare mo to answer this question, it would be good. (Fundamental linguistics Q's tend to be closed in favour of exotic or arcane or  obscurantist or specialist questions. These types of question need all the support they can get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gives is that there's a quirk in the logical interaction of *not* and *all* which, in the first sentence, gives rise to two opposed interpretations.

Interpretation 1: *not* is only negating *glitter*, and isn't applying to *all*. Then the reading is "For all X, if X is gold, then X does not glitter". This is the interpretation that's contradictory with your second sentence.

Interpretation 2: *not* is, despite its position, actually applying to *all*. This may seem illogical, but if you put some stress on *all*, it sounds more likely: "*All* that is gold doesn't glitter, only *some* gold things do". This interpretation (which is the one intended in Tolkien) is synonymous with your second sentence.

Comment: Choosing this as an answer, as manipulating intonation made the explanation immediately clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example has potentially two interpretations, with either "not" in the logical scope of "all" or "all" in the logical scope of "not".  There is no authority to appeal to who can tell us which is proper in English. I find that my own judgement fluctuates.  Logicians sometimes use linear order to distinguish the two interpretations, but probably more often use grouping symbols to tell one structure from the other.  Linguists can use trees.

Comment: I would call the word order very marked if *all* is supposed to be in the scope of *not*. I hadn't considered this possibility up until a minute ago. But it is not impossible.

Comment: We can use context to parse the correct meaning. Tolkien isn't trying to make some comment about the dullness of all Middle Earth gold, he's expressing that Aragorn's rough appearance belies his true virtue. In context, the two phrases are clearly synonymous and not contradictory.

Comment: @NuclearWang, I agree with what you say about Tolkien's  interpretation of this variation on an old saying.

Comment: @NuclearWang, well he isn't actually talking about gold, at all. So I don't quite agree with this argument. As I wrote below: The way I understood the "prophecy" is that the most valuable things never reveal their value at the first glance and that interpretation doesn't seem problematic to me.

Comment: " he isn't actually talking about gold" by that I mean, he doesn't mean it literally.

Answer (score 0):

[Before the Question was edited:]
Logically, they are **not** equivalent. 1. means that there is nothing that is gold and glitters.
2. means that there is something that glitters and is not gold.

[After the Question was edited:]
Well, then 1. means that if it is gold it doesn't glitter. x is gold → x does not glitter.

So, could you specify your question? The 2nd is based on the assumption that value is easily seen and states that, **no**, you can't always see the value of something.
The 1st statement is more drastic in that it says you can **never** see the value of something.
[gold could be seen as the metaphor(/ possibly metonymy) for the highest value there is]

[Another Edit:]
Nuclear Wang's post made me realize that 1. may be ambiguous. I stand by my interpretation but in very poetic speech the sentences could mean the same.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the question around a little bit, but my confusion remains!

Comment: @user2647513 Well, then 1. means that if it is gold it doesn't glitter. x is gold → x does not glitter.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of #1, since it's a patently false statement - there do exist gold objects that glitter. An outright false statement is no way to start a prophetic verse, so the opposite interpretation is probably the correct one.

Comment: @NuclearWang That's an interesting view. Logically you can make such a statement of course. The way I understood the "prophecy" is that the most valuable things **never** reveal their value at the first glance and that interpretation doesn't seem problematic to me. I think it fits and grammatically this is exactly how you would say it. – Now I understand why you only saw the opposite option, though, which I didn't before.

Answer (score 0):

These two phrases mean the exact same thing.

"Not all that is gold glitters" means that not every gold item glitters, or in other words, there are things with great value that may not appear so.

"All that is gold does not glitter" means the same, that not every gold item glitters. Some are parsing this sentence differently, suggesting it means that all gold items do not glitter. This interpretation is an outright falsehood, however, and doesn't fit at all within the context of a prophetic verse. Given the context, it should be interpreted that not all gold items glitter, not that all gold items do not glitter.

In the context of the poem, the phrase suggests that some people have hidden virtue. It does not suggest that all virtuous people outwardly appear otherwise.